# -0.1.ToString("0") is "-0" in .NET Core and "0" in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, tostring

```
(-0.1).ToString("0")
```

evaluates to "-0" in .NET Core and "0" in .NET Framework when value is double or float. On the other hand when value is decimal:

```
(-0.1M).ToString("0")
```

it evaluates to "0" in both frameworks.

Does anyone have more details on this change and which one is correct?

Comment: Technically they're both correct I suppose. Though I'd be tempted to log an issue for this behaviour.

Comment: I think it's covered in [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29157) and ultimately [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/) as this behaviour is only in .NET Core 3.

Comment: I saw the IEEE 754 standard and it says that positive zero and negative zero are two separate numbers, but this can potentially cause issues in existing software and it seems the guys from Microsoft do not provide a migration path.

Comment: The migration path is to be more careful in your output. If the system requires `0` instead of `-0` (which is a different number) then fix that system or fix your code.

Comment: I am working on a calculating engine mimicking the Excel behavior where you could set a number -0.01 in a cell and format it with a number format "0" or something else similar to that and you expect the result to be the same as in Excel. It worked in .NET Framework and now it is broken in .NET Core. So now I have to implement my custom ToString working like the old one?