# How to avoid "-0" as double.ToString() result after porting from .NET Framework 4.7.2 to .NET5.0?

Tags: c#, .net, double, tostring, .net-5

I am porting a .NET Framework 4.7.2 Visual Studio project to .NET5.0 and I am experiencing a different behaviour of double.ToString when the value is negative and close to zero.

For example, the double value -7.1054273576010019E-15 when converted to string returns "-0" even if I round it before the conversion while with the .NET Framework 4.7.2 its result was "0" (same code).

This difference is discussed here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/ but I don't really agree that this is an improvement as the title states, I believe 0 should not have a sign, it is neither a positive number nor a negative number.

I know I can create a custom IFormatProvider or an extension method and convert the double as I want but this requires a change in every conversion in the code and also any developers working on the project will need to use it in the future. In my opionion this solution is not very intuitive and it's likely to be source of errors.

Is there a way to restore the previous behaviour with less effort?
Is Microsoft willing to change this in the future versions of the .NET?

EDIT:
I asked the same thing in a discussion here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/54537
If it could be helpful to someone else.

Comment: You are using a very tiny number.  It is like saying the 0.99999999999999999 is one since it is very close to one.  In your case you have -1E-15, zero, +1E-15.  both -1E-15 and +1E-15 are the same distance to zero as 0.999999999999999 is to one.

Comment: Yes, I agree with what you are saying and that's indeed what i want when i round it. -1E-15 and +1E-15 after the round operation should both result as 0, instead I get -0 and 0. And this happens even if I assing a double to -0 (double x = -0;) so the problem is not really in the round method but instead in the double representation of 0 with a sign. I don't mind this behaviour untill i need to use the ToString() and that's what I am trying to solve with some workaround to get the same result as the previous .NET Framework.

Comment: There is no such thing as minus zero.  If Microsoft fixed a bug in a previous version of NET you do not want to still be using the bad results.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well. "There is no such thing as minus zero" this is true in the previous .NET Framework and it's what i want, instead in .NET5.0 the minus zero is allowed.

Comment: @jdweng In `double`, positive zero and negative zero have distinct representations. So when implementing `.ToString`, you have a choice whether you want to map positive zero and negative zero to the same string (.NET Framework), or to different strings (newer .NET).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linked post, it sounds like the change was made in order to be more compliant with IEEE 754, which is the behavior all languages try to be compliant with to minimize confusion - or at least standardize a particular form of confusion.

It's always possible that they will revert such changes if it becomes too backwards-incompatible and breaks people's programs en masse, but if it hasn't been done by this point (it's already in .NET Core 3.1, which is an LTS release, and in .NET 5) I don't think it will be. But asking here whether "Microsoft is willing to change this" is the wrong place - [file an issue in dotnet/runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime) and ask Microsoft directly.

The workaround needs to go everywhere but is also simple: replace **the exact string** "-0" with "0" (replacing the substring "-0" could lead to inverting the sign of -0.5, for example).

Comment: `ToString().Replace("-0","0")` might introduce bugs as it will change "-0.1" to "0.1", etc. 
Please update or remove this suggestion from last line

Answer (score 0):

`Math.Abs` will map both negative zero (which you may get from rounding, or in other ways) and positive zero into *positive* zero.

So instead of replacing `"-0"` with `"0"` as strings, you could use `Abs`.

But maybe you can also just do:

```cs
if (rounded == 0.0) {
    rounded = 0.0;  // POSITIVE zero
}
```

That should map both types of zero into the positive zero.

Inside an expression, that might be written as `rounded == 0.0 ? 0.0 : rounded`.

It is clear how you could write an extension method to `double` which will unite the two types of zeros (and leave all other `double` values unchanged).

Related questions here:

[-0.1.ToString("0") is "-0" in .NET Core and "0" in .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60266310/)

which is marked as a duplicate of:

[.net core 3 yields different floating point results from version 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59781786/)